# Recommended way to rerender page in Ember after language switch

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

I need to rerender whole page application after language has switched. I don't like to use observers for it because of performance issues.

Language switch is done by a `Ember.View`. I tried to rerender `parentView` after changing `Ember.I18n.translations` but running into a [known bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2267). It works one time but Ember Inspector shows parentView has dutzend of children views of it's own afterwards. After another switch parentView got destroyed. Just like demonstrated in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8k7Y/1/).

Here is simplified code of my view:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'language-switch',

  languageChanged: function() {
    // change language
    var language = this.get('controller.language.selected');
    Ember.I18n.translations = translations[language];

    // rerender page
    this.get('parentView').rerender();
  }.observes('controller.language.selected')
});
```

There is also a [discussion](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/refresh-current-view-page-after-language-change/4291/8) about that problem on discuss.emberjs.com. I tried the suggestions there but they don't work. Last post suggest a work-a-round to map over all views, rerender them and afterwards use a transition. I don't like that one since I am afraid getting side problems by that hack.

I am pretty sure there must be a way to do a language switch in Ember with ember-i18n but what's the right way to do that?

---

Update:

I tried to implement the hack from discuss.emberjs.com. It's working but it's very limited. I implement it like this in the view:

```
var self = this;
var currentRoute = self.get('controller.currentRouteName');
this.get('controller.target').transitionTo('loading').then(function(){
    self.get('controller.target').transitionTo(currentRoute);
});
```

Problem is that all data stored in model is lost. I did not find a way to get the current model and use it in transition. Also query parameters are lost. That limitation makes this work-a-round unacceptable for my application.

---

Update App.reset():

As suggested in comment I tried to use `App.reset()`. It works better than transitionTo work-a-round but doesn't match all needs. If calling App.reset() queryParams aren't lost but model is reseted. I'm looking for a way to rerender application while keeping current model and queryParams.

---

It seems that mostly these problem is handled by a full page reload on locale change. E.q. one of the main developers of ember-i18n said so in [this discussion](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/issues/132).

Comment: Have you tried calling `App.reset()`?

Comment: @SteveH. just tried and updated question. `App.reset()` seems to be the best way yet but doesn't do the job well.